# java-script google function code triggered by firestore does not work properly

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm going to use google cloud function to calculate avg ratings when users add their review of restaurants on my android app.

What I'm trying to do is:
When a user clicks the submit button, the rating should be added to the firestore. And then the google cloud function should be triggered.
This function calculates avg rating and updates data.

I wrote the following code, but it does not work well.

I expected the avg rating to be averaged, but it is replaced by the score of the last user review.

// Edit Question

// Problem is console.log(old numRatings) and consold.log(oldRatingTotal) are
      always zero,,,even though actual data aren't zero.

Below is Android App code

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){

            case R.id.btn_submit :
                if(String.valueOf(mEtxTitle.getText()) != "null"
                && String.valueOf(mEtxContent.getText()) != "null"){
                    submit();

    }

private void submit() {

        if(retrieveDataFlag){
            setVars();

            final DocumentReference documentReference = db.collection("restaurants").document(mPlace.getId());

            // add default restaurant info to document
            updateRestaurant(documentReference, restaurant);

            // add location to document
            addLocation(documentReference, mGeoPoint);

            // add user review to document
            addReview(documentReference, review, rating);

            // upload photo and download url and add it to document
            if(mImageUris != null){
                addPhoto(storageRef, documentReference, mImageUris);
            }
            finish();

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"No Place Data retrived", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Below is Restaurant class

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class Restaurant {

    public String name;
    public int numRatings;
    public double avgRating;
    public String id;
    public String address;
    public String website_uri;
    public String phone_number;
    public String opening_hours;
    public String price_level;
    public @ServerTimestamp Timestamp timestamp;

...
...

}
```

```
    private void addReview(final DocumentReference restaurantRef, final Map<String, String> review, final Map<String, Float> rating){
        restaurantRef.collection("reviews").document().set(review);
        restaurantRef.collection("ratings").document().set(rating);
    }
```

And this is google cloud function

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();
// [START_EXCLUDE]
const settings = {timestampsInSnapshots: true};
db.settings(settings);
// [END_EXCLUDE]

// [START aggregate_function]
exports.aggregateRatings = functions.firestore
    .document('restaurants/{restId}/ratings/{ratingId}')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {
      // Get value of the newly added rating
      var ratingVal = change.after.data().rating;
      console.log(ratingVal)

      // Get a reference to the restaurant
      var restRef = db.collection('restaurants').doc(context.params.restId);

      // Update aggregations in a transaction
      return db.runTransaction(transaction => {
        return transaction.get(restRef).then(restDoc => {
          // Compute new number of ratings
          var newNumRatings = restDoc.data().numRatings + 1;
          console.log("resDoc", restDoc.data())
          console.log("old numRatings : ", restDoc.data().numRatings)
          console.log("new numRatings : ", newNumRatings)

          // Compute new average rating
          var oldRatingTotal = restDoc.data().avgRating * restDoc.data().numRatings;
          console.log("oldRatingTotla : " ,oldRatingTotal)

          var newAvgRating = (oldRatingTotal + ratingVal) / newNumRatings;
          console.log("new AvgRating : ", newAvgRating)

          // Update restaurant info
          return transaction.update(restRef, {
            avgRating: newAvgRating,
            numRatings: newNumRatings
          });
        });
      });
    });
// [END aggregate_function]
```

this is log
function triggered twice, but avgRating and numRatings value are '0'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tcKw.png)

Comment: Please specify the exact problem instead of saying that it does not work properly. This makes it easier to help.

Comment: In particular, do you get any error in the Cloud Function console?

Comment: FYI, I've tested your Cloud Function and it works as expected. Are you sure you write the correct data, with correct format (number)?

Comment: I added console.log and found that restDoc.data().numRatings and restDoc.data().avgRating are always '0'

Comment: data stored with type number. and no error code, In Log, Function finished with status : 'ok'